# jQuery trigger action when a user scrolls past a certain part of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all, I need a jQuery action to fire when a user scrolls past certain locations on the page. Is this even possible with jQuery? I have looked at .scroll in the jQuery API and I don't think this is what I need. It fires every time the user scrolls, but I need it to fire just when a user passes a certain area.

Answer (score 49):

Use the jquery event .scroll()

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 150;             // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/babumxx/hpXL4/

Comment: I tested it with 

$("header, footer").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fd9c3d" }, 1200);

in the if statement and it does not appear to be working

Comment: just put an alert to test if the event is firing, inside and outside the if statement.

Answer (score 19):

Waypoints in jQuery should do it:
http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

```
$('#my-el').waypoint(function(direction) {
  console.log('Reached ' + this.element.id + ' from ' + direction + ' direction.');
});
```

jQuery waypoints plugin documentation: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/

Comment: Just used waypoints.js on a parallax single page scrolling app. works excellent. One tip I can give you is to use links for waypoints. Set the visibility to hidden. You can use absolute positioning to set height of waypoint. <a class="waypoint screen-1-1" style="top:120px">Screen 1-1</a>.

Answer (score 11):

To fire any action only once on a single page I have modified jondavid's snippet as following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $triggered_times = 0;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

            var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
            var scroll_pos_test = 150;   // set to whatever you want it to be

            if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && $triggered_times == 0 ) {

                //do your stuff over here

                $triggered_times = 1;   // to make sure the above action triggers only once

            }
    });

})
```

### Scroll down to Run code snippet

Here you can check example of working code snippet;

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $triggered_times = 0;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 150;   // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && $triggered_times == 0 ) {
     alert('This alert is triggered after you have scroll down to 150px')
     $triggered_times = 1;   // to make sure the above action triggers only once
    }
  });

 })
```

```css
p {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>scroll down this block to get an alert</p>
</body>
```

Comment: why is there a `$` symbol in the `document.ready` function? If I put that it works or else it doesn't work. Reason? @Mursaleen

Comment: actually sometimes `$` in not defined like in case of WordPress but `jQuery` is defined over there. So here by placing it in `function($){ ...  }`  means `$=jQuery` . Thats why if you remove `$` sign from above code it might stop working in some cases.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks