# Check if scrollbar is scrolled down a half

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check the scrollbar is scrolled down a half.

I mean when the user scrolls down over a half of screen, it should alert a message.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957658/trigger-jquery-function-when-passed-half-way-down-the-page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

since you are using jquery, you could use [jQuery.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()  > $(window).height() / 2) {        
        alert('At Half the screen');
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. After scrolling to the end scrollTop value is 693 and `$(window).height()/2` value is 745

Answer (score 0):

You can get the half of the visible screen by

```
$(window).height() / 2
```

Half of the entire size of your page would be

```
$(document).height() / 2
```

Then compare the result against the scroll position:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mHeight = $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var sPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
        if(sPosition > (mHeight/2)) alert('hola :)');
    });
});
```