# How to scroll the page itself at a point with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written i snippet of code here to demonstrate more clearly: 
https://jsfiddle.net/u73r6ypp/

```
<div id="header">Fade me away</div>
<div id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```

What I want is, as u scroll the page down, the header div will fade out, but at a point, for instance last 20% of the header element the page will scroll itself (animate/transition) to the next element which will come from the top of the window.

I hope you do understand my request and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has support for this using the `animate` function.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoscrolltoo").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

This will scroll the page down to the element you specify in 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks buddy, but how would you set the condition from where to animate the page?

Comment: @AmirRami use the `scroll()` event to watch for scrolling, and then use the `scrollTop()` to get how get how many pixels down the element you are and compare that to the height of the page. When the condition is met, trigger this code. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957658/trigger-jquery-function-when-passed-half-way-down-the-page) for a more whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about jquery but there's a far easier method using JavaScript.
Simply type in:

```
function scrollSample() {
window.scrollTo (x,y);
}
```

Then call the function in html.
That should scroll you to the desired point if you replace *x* and *y* with the values you want.