# jquery on scroll change the menu bar height and logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how can I check if the user scrolls down?
I have a menubar at the top of the page with a logo.
And if the user scrolls down I want to resize or change the logo (smaller), change the height of the menu bar and make the position fixed.

Thanks

Comment: try using google ("jquery if user scrolls") and then click on first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627203/jquery-trigger-action-when-a-user-scrolls-past-a-certain-part-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  //when window is scrolled
 //change image size and height of menu bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99yFJ/5/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#navbar').css('position','fixed');
    $('#id').attr('width', '100px');
    $('#id2').css('font-size', '12px');
});
```

I updated the code now is fixed to top on scrol down.