# Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

I have an h1 that is far down a page..

```
<h1 id="scroll-to">TRIGGER EVENT WHEN SCROLLED TO.</h1>
```

and I want to trigger an alert when the user scrolls to the h1, or has it in it's browser's view.

```
$('#scroll-to').scroll(function() {
     alert('you have scrolled to the h1!');
});
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can calculate the `offset` of the element and then compare that with the `scroll` value like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
       console.log('H1 on the view!');
   }
});
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/)**

---

Updated [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/279/) no alert -- instead FadeIn() the element

---

Updated code to check if the element is inside the viewport or not. Thus this works whether you are scrolling up or down adding some rules to the if statement:

```
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
       //Do something
   }
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/636/)**

Comment: Debounce this please!

Comment: Is there any package library that does this as a function like jQuery Waypoint?

Comment: How would you get this event to fire just once, or stop triggering if it already hit.

Comment: @ClosDesign you can use `.off()`to unbind the event http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/543/

Comment: You can add the ff test in your if statement to check if the element is in the viewport or not and not just past the current scroll `&& (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)`

Comment: @Paolo thanks for the suggest feel free to edit the post adding your example and that extra functionality after the answer.

Comment: @DaniP I just did , thanks! And thanks for the answer, helped me a lot :)

Comment: Apparently the **target element must not have** a `display:none`, took me a few minutes to figure that out.

Comment: what if $('#scroll-to') is a collection of more that 1 element , of an accordion for example and i want this event to be triggered on every scroll to every element inside this , thank you

Comment: is using scroll event like this efficient ?

Answer (score 32):

Combining this question with the best answer from [jQuery trigger action when a user scrolls past a certain part of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627203/jquery-trigger-action-when-a-user-scrolls-past-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

```
var element_position = $('#scroll-to').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = element_position;

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I've improved the code so that it will trigger when the element is half way up the screen rather than at the very top. It will also trigger the code if the user hits the bottom of the screen and the function hasn't fired yet.

```
var element_position = $('#scroll-to').offset().top;
var screen_height = $(window).height();
var activation_offset = 0.5;//determines how far up the the page the element needs to be before triggering the function
var activation_point = element_position - (screen_height * activation_offset);
var max_scroll_height = $('body').height() - screen_height - 5;//-5 for a little bit of buffer

//Does something when user scrolls to it OR
//Does it when user has reached the bottom of the page and hasn't triggered the function yet
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;

    var element_in_view = y_scroll_pos > activation_point;
    var has_reached_bottom_of_page = max_scroll_height <= y_scroll_pos && !element_in_view;

    if(element_in_view || has_reached_bottom_of_page) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that 'pageYOffset' is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

I think your best bet would be to leverage an existing library that does that very thing:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

You can add listeners to your elements that will fire off when your element hits the top of the viewport:

```
$('#scroll-to').waypoint(function() {
 alert('you have scrolled to the h1!');
});
```

For an amazing demo of it in use:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/16/on-scroll-header-effects/

Comment: I've already tried this. It only triggers once you've scrolled PAST the element. Any other solutions?

Comment: This solution works well to fetch recommendations and I have used it in production. Refer to the blog: https://liyao13.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/8-html-css-javascript-and-mongodb-tips/

Answer (score 7):

Inview library triggered event and works well with jquery 1.8 and higher!
https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

```
$('div').on('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});
```

Read this https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin

Answer (score 7):

**Fire scroll only *once* after a successful scroll**

> **Note**: By successful scroll I mean when the user has scrolled to the desired
> element or in other words when the desired element is in view

The accepted answer worked 90% for me so I had to tweak it a little to actually fire only once.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var hT = $('#comment-box-section').offset().top,
    hH = $('#comment-box-section').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > ((hT+hH-wH)-500)){
        console.log('comment box section arrived! eh');
        // This detaches the scroll so doStuff() won't run more than once
        $(window).off('scroll');
        doStuff();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use this for all devices,

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= $('#target_element').position().top ){
        do_something();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Intersection Observer can be the best thing IMO, without any external library it does a really good job.

```
const options = {
            root: null,
            threshold: 0.25, // 0 - 1 this work as a trigger. 
            rootMargin: '150px'
        };

        const target = document.querySelector('h1#scroll-to');
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
           entries => { // each entry checks if the element is the view or not and if yes trigger the function accordingly
            entries.forEach(() => {
                alert('you have scrolled to the h1!')
            });
        }, options);
        observer.observe(target);
```

Comment: This unfortunately displays the alert twice - once when the observer is initialized, and once when the target appears. One way to solve this would be to use isVisible, but this function was only implemented in IntersectionObserver V2, which is [still only supported by Chrome](https://caniuse.com/?search=isvisible).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery plugin](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin) with the `inview` event like this :

```
jQuery('.your-class-here').one('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
      //Enjoy !
    }
});
```

Link : https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need.

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $('#circle').offset().top,
        hH = $('#circle').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT - wH), wS);
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 900,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        }); {
            $('.count').removeClass('count').addClass('counted');
        };
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#circle
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
.count, .counted
{
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  margin-left:30px;
  font-size:25px;
}
#talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   background: green;
   position: relative;
   -moz-border-radius:    10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius:         10px;
   float:left;
   margin:20px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   top: 15px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid green;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">145</span></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="talkbubble"><span class="count">145</span></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="circle"><span class="count">1234</span></div>
```

Check this bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/atin_agarwal2/cJBywxX5Qp

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a **javascript version**. You can call this method on **scroll event listener.**

```
  showScrollTop = () =>{
    const currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset; 
    let elementID = 'service-selector'
    const elementOffsetTop = document.getElementById(elementID).offsetTop

    if ( currentScrollPosition > elementOffsetTop){
     // place your logic here 
    } else {
      // place your logic here 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', showScrollTop)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a lot of functionality based on scroll position, Scroll magic (http://scrollmagic.io/) is built entirely for this purpose.

It makes it easy to trigger JS based on when the user reaches certain elements when scrolling. It also integrates with the GSAP animation engine (https://greensock.com/) which is great for parallax scrolling websites

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick modification to DaniP's answer, for anyone dealing with elements that can sometimes extend beyond the bounds of the device's viewport.

Added just a slight conditional - In the case of elements that are bigger than the viewport, the element will be revealed once it's top half has completely filled the viewport.

```
function elementInView(el) {
  // The vertical distance between the top of the page and the top of the element.
  var elementOffset = $(el).offset().top;
  // The height of the element, including padding and borders.
  var elementOuterHeight = $(el).outerHeight();
  // Height of the window without margins, padding, borders.
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  // The vertical distance between the top of the page and the top of the viewport.
  var scrollOffset = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (elementOuterHeight < windowHeight) {
    // Element is smaller than viewport.
    if (scrollOffset > (elementOffset + elementOuterHeight - windowHeight)) {
      // Element is completely inside viewport, reveal the element!
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    // Element is larger than the viewport, handle visibility differently.
    // Consider it visible as soon as it's top half has filled the viewport.
    if (scrollOffset > elementOffset) {
      // The top of the viewport has touched the top of the element, reveal the element!
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use less cryptic variable names, even if accepted answer uses them.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code doing that all the time, so added a simple jquery plugin doing it.
480 bytes long, and fast. Only bound elements analyzed in runtime.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-on-scrolled-to

It will be

`$('#scroll-to').onScrolledTo(0, function() {
    alert('you have scrolled to the h1!');
});`

or use 0.5 instead of 0 if need to alert when half of the h1 shown.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and fast implementation,

```
let triggered = false;
 $(window).on('scroll',function() { 
        if (window.scrollY > ($('#scrollTo').offset().top+$('#scrollTo').outerHeight()-window.innerHeight) & !triggered){
            console.log('triggered here on scroll..');
            triggered = true;
        }
     });
```

using global variable `triggered = false` makes it just to happen once, otherwise, every time crossing past the element, this action is triggered.