# JQuery, scroll to element in different divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there is anyway in JQuery to scroll to elements that are inside different divs. For example, if I go to example.com/programme#event-2, div on the left should scroll to element id="event-2", and div on the right should scroll to element id="event-2". Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="events">
    <div id="event-list">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Vendredi 17 octobre</h2>
            <ul id="event-1" class="event-title">
                list items
            </ul>
            <h2>Vendredi 21 octobre</h2>
            <ul id="event-2" class="event-title">
                list-items
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="event-details">
        <div class="content">
            <section id="event-1" class="details">
                stuff
            </section>

            <section id="event-2" class="details">
                stuff
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can have a look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/LVYWWE), it will help visualize my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: These articles on SO may help :) [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element), [Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Thank you! First article you mentioned had the solution. Added jquery instruction to the codepen if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 0):

here is link to example : [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/RPwVax)

First of all IMPORTANT

Id can be use only once and u use it like class #event-1 etc

second I create button for first columns, red "scroll"

```
$(function(){
  var thisOffset = $("#event-5").offset().top; // get element top offset 


  $(".scroll").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("scroll")
     $("#event-list .content").animate({  //scroll to specific offset on click 
       scrollTop: thisOffset
     }, 1000)
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know that id's are for one element only, that's just how I started. I'm going to change to classes. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: There is something weird happening with your code (and mine). When changing `var thisOffset = $("#event-5").offset().top;` to `var thisOffset = $("#event-2").offset().top;`, and `$("#event-list .content").animate({` to `$("#event-details .content").animate({`, the scrolling stops before reaching the element on the second column. Any idea why?