# fadeIn() effect in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in javascript. I want you scroll through the pages in a specific place appeared in the text. I try to do this using fadeIn (), but does not go to me. Browser do not see any effect. I would be very grateful for an explanation.

```
 <div id="about_content">
        <p id="randomText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
 </div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".randomText").fadeIn('slow');
    );

</script>

#about_content{
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 70vw;
height:50vh;
background-color: pink;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
top:25vh;
padding:20px;
   }

#randomText {

font-size:1.5em;

 }
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, are you trying to have the fade in occur when the user scrolls to a certain point in the page?

Comment: Besides you using the wrong selector, `fadeIn` will only fade in an element that is not currently visible: eg `display:none`

Comment: Yes, exactly when the user scroll to the place where the text is

Answer (score 0):

```
function testScroll(ev){
    if(window.pageYOffset>400){
        $('#randomText').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}
window.onscroll=testScroll
```

Instead you can use jQuery's Scroll http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: It still does not work. I do not know why, it looks like that my browser does not support JQuery...

Comment: which browser and which version you're using ?

Comment: Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m 
Firefox 46.0.1

Comment: open console and type `$` see what you're getting. if it returns something your browser probably supporting jQuery else it will return `$ undefinded`.

Comment: in console check your network tab if the jQuery.js file is included properly.

Comment: It seems that all is well.

Comment: just make sure you're not including your `script` file before `jQuery`.

Comment: Can you specific how the code is not working? Since the condition is set to `window.pageYOffset >400`, so the fade in animation of element will only be fired when the y offset is greater is 400. Try to add a `console.log('test')` before the if and open the console to see if `test` is output.

Comment: I tried to use a different script and it worked. Just the code you provided above does not work. I do not understand this..

Comment: ok I solved this. I added in the head <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  instead of <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and everything is OK now. Thanks for you effort

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a bit messy. I believe your want to embed your CSS inside the HTML, but you should enclose the CSS inside a `<style>` tag.

And back to you question, the reason why the `fadeIn()` does not work is that you are using the wrong selector and you are not hiding the element at first load. `$(".randomText")` select the element with class name `randomText` but in your HTML code `<p id="randomText">...` `randomText` is the id. On the other hand, you should also add CSS property `display: none` to the `#randomText` element.

Second, you want to fade in only when user scroll to the text, so you will have to bind the `scroll` event to a listener. And in the listener you determine if it has reached the text element. If yes then it should fade in the text. 
Reference: [Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery)

So a fix will be changing the JavaScript to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var el = $('#randomText');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > el.offset().top+el.outerHeight()-$(this).height()) {
            $('#randomText').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

and in your CSS add:

```
#randomText {
    display: none;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnyth81e/

Comment: @MateuszGorzelak One of the possible causes is that `$('#randomText')` cannot query the element. Is it possible for you to copy the whole file content to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and/or update your question for me to have a look?