# Adding css animation when it is scrolled to the CLASS ELEMENT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's surely simple question but i didn't find what i want.
I need css animation (which is class) to add to class element when user scroll to it's Y position (be able to see it).

For example i have one class called `AnimationClass`

**Here is my css animation:**

```
.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

So when user scroll to element Y position add this class to element class. I don't want to use `if (scroll <= 500)` .

**Update:** U wrote down that there is a lot of similar question. But i need **CLASS** element to animate, **not ID**. I don't know how to write it in javascript.

Comment: You could have a look at http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I'm not good with javascript, that's why i asked this.

Comment: Also here more answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/21561480/2887133

Comment: This elemnts is id not class.

Comment: @pHenomen You can select on a class and not an ID. Your question has been asked before. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery) uses an ID but could easily be switched out for a class.