# Do something on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, scroll

What is the best way if I want to animate an element on scroll?
because I noticed that it lags a little bit while scrolling.
should I add the class like this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
     $(".element").addClass("animateElement");
   }
}
```

or make a flag like this one.

```
animateFlag = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
     if(animateFlag) {
         $(".element").addClass("animateElement");
         animateFlag = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `addClass` without flag will add class `animateElement` to the element on each scroll you do once you cross your threshold point. Where as via second approach the class will get added only once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to animate something on scroll is to make the most optimized code. For example, you could use Vanilla JS with a flag like you described and also query for the element before scrolling which would result in something like so:

```js
var animateFlag = true
var element = document.querySelector(".element")

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if(this.pageYOffset > 0) {
    if(animateFlag) {
      element.classList.add("animateElement");
      animateFlag = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.element {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.element.animateElement {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```