# jquery toggle that closes on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have a very difficult client that is demanding that a jquery toggle closes when a user scrolls down the page, rather than automatically staying open / closing when a user collapses it...

would that be possible?  My jquery is pretty simple...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-toggle2').click(function() {
    //get collapse content selector
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
    var toggle_switch = $(this);
    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
      if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        //change the button label to be 'Show'
        toggle_switch.html('Contact Us');
      } else {
        //change the button label to be 'Hide'
        toggle_switch.html('Contact Us <');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tag href="#contactus" class="nav-toggle2">Contact Us &lt;</tag>
<div id="contactus">some content that hides/shows here</div>
```

I can get around in jquery but am a little naive when it somes to integrating new effects into it.... would it be possible to have toggle_switch.html on scroll so when a user gets maybe 1/3 the page down, it hides?

Comment: Ignore the duplicate flag.  Pick an element that when scrolled to you want the toggle to close and then I would look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery) answer.

Comment: have you tried listening to the scroll event of the page and call toggle(false) when onScroll?

Comment: hmm I have not @blenzcoffee, that might be a good idea... can you possibly provide a link / example to that?  I've done something kind of like that with sticky headers like on this site: mcadamsplumbing.com but I don't know how I could get something like that to "talk" with the .navtoggle2 function?

Comment: @Mixmastermiike I post a sample code. It's not tested so you may need to tweak it, but that will be a good starting point how to talk to navtoggle2. You may want to check the link posted by lamelemon

Comment: @Mixmastermiike does it work?

Comment: hmm sorry that didn't work - thanks for the suggestion though. I'll post the code I used, I might have messed it up

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you said you haven't tried listening to the scroll event. Can you try that?
It will be something like this (code not tested):

```
  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        // you can replace this with your hiding toggle logic 
        $('.nav-toggle2').toggle('false');
  });
```

You may want to unbind the event from the window later to avoid memory leak. 
Reference about scroll: [Jquery scroll api](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: so basically put that script above all the jquery stuff?
      $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        // you can replace this with your hiding toggle logic 
        $('.nav-toggle2').toggle('false');
      });