# Piwik Single Page Tracking

Tags: matomo

Besides using a heartbeat to frequently ping the visitor and calculate the time on site or page, is there a way to measure single page scrolling activity with Piwik? Can some JavaScript be used within different  ids on the page to trigger an "event" that Piwik will track?

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the scroll event to fire a Piwik page view. A few solutions for how to detect what area of the page the user has scrolled to can be found [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery).