# Owl carousel autoplay only on containing section focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, owl-carousel, autoplay

I have included owl carousel inside a section tag in JSP . My requirement is that owl carousel should autoplay only when the user scroll to that section. And it should pause when user scrolls down to another  section and continue to autoplay when user scrolls up to that containing section. Tried several methods , but not working. If anyone could help me with it would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery It may help you.

Comment: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/

Answer (score 1):

normally this thing not possible by scroll down, but for this thing, you can add autoplay when carousel visible but it is working only on mouseover

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true
});

$('.section').on("mouseenter", function(e) {
    owl.trigger('owl.play', 2000);
})
```