# Trigger a js animation when the page is scrolled to the section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a the easy Pie Chart plugin from rendro (https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/). Basically I only want the animation to happen only when I scroll to the specific area on the page in which the chart is displayed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery

Comment: This is excellent!! I'm new to jQuery and didn't know bout the $(window).scroll function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

**Pros**:

- No need to add scroll listener, debounce function.
- Code is much clearer and smaller.

**Cons**:

- Support is lacking in Safari, so you'll need to add a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill).

```js
function handler(entries, observer) {
  for (entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add('inView');
    }
  }
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler);
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".takeAction"));
```

```css
.takeAction {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 3s background-color;
}

.takeAction.inView {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p class="takeAction">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia nisi laborum consequuntur quis architecto ullam cupiditate ipsam repellendus quos magnam a recusandae, tenetur veniam eos praesentium iure optio dicta, ex.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/30unpcLm/2/

Comment: This seems like a really good solution but I've been trying to write the code and play around with it for the past 1.5h with no success. From what I read so far and if I understand correctly, the Intersection Observer API work with CSS animations. Am I right? If that's the case, this won't work because the animations in the Easy Pie Chart code are done through jQuery.

Comment: That's not correct. You can call/do whatever you'd like when the entry is intersected. Instead of adding a CSS class, as in my example, you could execute the `$('.chart').easyPieChart({});`