# Bootstrap 4 - How to make fixed-top navbar disappear on scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, how can I make the fixed-top navbar disappear on scroll? I've attached below the html code for the default Bootstrap 4 navbar.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-md-2">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The purpose of "fixed" is to keep it in place when scrolling. So why not remove `fixed-top` instead?

Comment: I want to keep it fixed but want it to disappear during the scrolling process after a certain amount has been scrolled. For example, after 700px down the page I want the navbar to disappear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cue beat me too it. Similar to his answer but not using short code.

**jQuery**

```
// scroll functions
$(window).scroll(function(e) {

    // add/remove class to navbar when scrolling to hide/show
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 150) {
        $('.navbar').addClass("navbar-hide");
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-hide");
    }

});
```

**CSS navbar fade out option**

Codeply demo https://www.codeply.com/go/rTR1dcn4n6

```
.navbar {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-hide {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**CSS navbar slide up option**

Codeply demo https://www.codeply.com/go/7Fab8Thufl

```
.navbar {
    transition: top 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-hide {
    top: -56px;
}
```

---

Cue's answer is probably much better if you like less code, here is his method below using my hide class.

**Cue's jQuery**

```
// scroll functions
$(window).scroll(function(e) {

    // add/remove class to navbar when scrolling to hide/show
    $('.navbar')[$(window).scrollTop() >= 150 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('navbar-hide');

});
```

**CSS navbar fade out option (same as above)**

Codeply demo https://www.codeply.com/go/KPnx8ewEED

**CSS navbar slide up option (same as above)**

Codeply demo https://www.codeply.com/go/i82vYBGeu7

Comment: That's what happens when you elaborate as much as you have but I much prefer this visually working version in all honesty. Good example.

Comment: @Cue thanks man, though i learnt a lot from your code. Did not know you could use jQuery functions like that, clever!

Comment: as the saying goes “every day is a school day”

Answer (score 5):

To conditionally remove the fixed positioning of the navbar when you've reached a certain offset (in this example we'll use 150px from top of viewport) then you could do:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
  $('.navbar')[$(window).scrollTop() >= 150 ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('fixed-top');
})
```

As per [ajax333221](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164397/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-fixed-top-navbar-disappear-on-scroll/54164579?noredirect=1#comment95172723_54164579)'s comment, `toggleClass()` could also be used:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
  $('.navbar').toggleClass('fixed-top', $(window).scrollTop() < 150);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but how can I make it less choppy and more of a fade out?

Comment: See @joshmoto example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164631/2150268)

Comment: perhaps `.toggleClass( className, state )` could be used instead: _A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or removed._

Comment: @ajax333221 updated to reflect your suggestion. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Fixed-top forces the navigation to remain **fixed** to the top of the viewport.

> "An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
>   viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
>   page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
>   to position the element."

Html elements natively move as you scroll down. If you want the navigation to scroll with the content, then you need to remove this class.

Comment: fixed-top keeps the navbar at the top of the browser when scrolling. I want to keep it at the top but I want it to disappear using jquery after scrolling certain length down the page

Comment: Accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery