# Hide a fixed Div, when footer Div shows up in the screen while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a fixed Div at the bottom, I want to hide that fixed div when a footer div start showing in the screen when I scroll the page down and also show the fixed div back when I Scroll up.

```css
.content{
height:600px;
font-size:30px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;}

.fixedDiv{
   padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    z-index: 10;
}

.footerDiv{
background:red;
height:300px;
width:100%;
font-size:30px;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">CONTENT
</div>
<div class="fixedDiv">Hide Me When Footer Comes</div>
<div class="footerDiv">FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: This could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery

Comment: Please check the complete solution and jsfiddle i posted below. If it works please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After improvising this little [How to Check if element is visible after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   if (isScrolledIntoView('.footerDiv') )
     $('.fixedDiv').css('visibility','hidden');      
   else{
     $('.fixedDiv').css('visibility','visible');
  }
});


function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();    
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;    
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();   

  return ((elemTop < docViewBottom));
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t0uogj3v/

Comment: Thank You, Murali, The Solution Worked.

Comment: I Marked the answer but it shows "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."