# Store Section on viewport as variable value - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function to trigger actions depending on the current section showing on the viewport.

I've managed to track if a specific section is on the viewport using this great answer by DaniP

[Trigger event when user scroll to specific element - with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery/21561584#21561584)

Now I'm trying to store the current section as a value in a `current_section` variable

```js
var current_section = $('#1');

function SectionTracking(section) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var hT = $(section).offset().top,
          hH = $(section).outerHeight(),
          wH = $(window).height(),
          wS = $(this).scrollTop()
        if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
          console.log('yes');
          section.addClass('active');
          current_section = section;
        }
    });
}

SectionTracking($('#4'));
```

```css
.event-background {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.event-background.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Index">
  <section class="Index-page">
    <div class="event-background" id="1">
      Section 1
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="2">
      Section 2
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="3">
      Section 3
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="4"> 
      Section 4
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="5">
      Section 5
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="6">
      Section 6
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="7">
      Section 7
    </div>
    <div class="event-background" id="8">
      Section 8
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Prototype:
https://codepen.io/VictorSavas/pen/MWgZGoY

PS: among other actions, my main goal with this is to have a single fixed button that scrolls to the next section, i want to use the `current_section` variable to scroll to the next one.

Thank you in advance