# Adjust Element Position to 0 on window scroll in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page contain a fixed position of Table of Content,and a long text under neath banner image.

On window scroll event, my table of content leaves a lot of space from the top. That I try to make it, my table of content section, stay at position 0 on window scrolling, and when the window scroll is at position 0 I want it stay exactly underneath the banner image. But it does not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navSelector = '#toc';
  var $myNav = $(navSelector);

  Toc.init({
    $nav: $myNav,
    $scope: $('.releasenote')
  });

  $('nav#toc ul:first-child').remove();

});
```

```css
nav[data-toggle='toc'] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- add after bootstrap.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.4.1/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.css">
<!-- add after bootstrap.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.4.1/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!-- <link href="dist/bootstrap-toc.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#toc">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/900x400/000/fff" alt="" style="margin: 10px auto;">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- sidebar, which will move to the top on a small screen -->
      <!-- main content area -->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <nav id="toc" class="affix toc-nav" data-spy="affix" data-toggle="toc"></nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9">

        <!-- <div id="menu1" > -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="pbox releasenote">

            <h1 class="text-center" id="release-note">Release Note</h1>
            <h1>0.1.4 (2020-07-06)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed install package from test server via command line.</li>
              <li>Setup tool is able to include icon.</li>
              <li>Read package file from archive format whl and gz file.</li>
              <li>Flexiable Package icon .png or .icon</li>
              <li>Link with tab by link NEWS.rst or CHANGELOG.md.</li>
              <li>Fixed reverse package push record and package record.</li>
              <li>Data clean up on server test, production or both.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.3 (2020-07-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed error package push on reverse record.</li>
              <li>Change browser title, icon, and update footer.</li>
              <li>Fixed error on URL Project when user does not follow our pre-formate in setup.py file.</li>
              <li>Add field PkgVersion to table MKT_PKG_ACCESS_DE to filter package by version</li>
              <li>Able to use ALL keyword in version grant package access to all version.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.2 (2020-06-26)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Update tab title to Morakot Private Package</li>
              <li>Add package platform in user activity</li>
              <li>Download now is classified by version and platform </li>
              <li>User in Morakot Organization and in Test server default can access all pacakge in test server</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.1 (2020-06-21)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Cut branch dev from master</li>
              <li>Add Modules, forms and models</li>
              <li>Adding host, port, http type as configuration</li>
              <li>Adding install and upload instructions</li>
              <li>Update pip install command line.</li>
              <li>Add new widget new release.</li>
              <li>Update user activity to sort by date descending.</li>
              <li>Package user in release history.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.0 (2020-01-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Initial project first version</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.4 (2020-07-06)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed install package from test server via command line.</li>
              <li>Setup tool is able to include icon.</li>
              <li>Read package file from archive format whl and gz file.</li>
              <li>Flexiable Package icon .png or .icon</li>
              <li>Link with tab by link NEWS.rst or CHANGELOG.md.</li>
              <li>Fixed reverse package push record and package record.</li>
              <li>Data clean up on server test, production or both.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.3 (2020-07-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed error package push on reverse record.</li>
              <li>Change browser title, icon, and update footer.</li>
              <li>Fixed error on URL Project when user does not follow our pre-formate in setup.py file.</li>
              <li>Add field PkgVersion to table MKT_PKG_ACCESS_DE to filter package by version</li>
              <li>Able to use ALL keyword in version grant package access to all version.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.2 (2020-06-26)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Update tab title to Morakot Private Package</li>
              <li>Add package platform in user activity</li>
              <li>Download now is classified by version and platform </li>
              <li>User in Morakot Organization and in Test server default can access all pacakge in test server</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.1 (2020-06-21)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Cut branch dev from master</li>
              <li>Add Modules, forms and models</li>
              <li>Adding host, port, http type as configuration</li>
              <li>Adding install and upload instructions</li>
              <li>Update pip install command line.</li>
              <li>Add new widget new release.</li>
              <li>Update user activity to sort by date descending.</li>
              <li>Package user in release history.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.0 (2020-01-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Initial project first version</li>
            </ul>


          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- </div> tab 2 -->

        <!-- /End Tab -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My js to fix my table of content top margin is here but seem it does not work.

```
    /* fix Table of Content top margin on Scroll */
    // var CurrentScroll = $(window).offset().top; //.scrollTop()
    var ElementY = $('#toc').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log(ElementY);
        if (ElementY >= 400) {
            // alert(CurrentScroll);
            $('#toc').css('top', ElementY - 400);
        }else
        {
            $('#toc').css('top', ElementY);
        }
    });
```

Any tip how can I achieve this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: You could use `position:sticky` if you don't worry about browser support too much. See compatibility table here: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: @Will, thanks so much,  I tried `#toc {position: sticky;}` but it does not work.

Comment: @Will, Thanks have a look at an answer :)

Comment: Glad you figure it out. But if you want to use sticky in the future, you need to set the top CSS property for sticky to work. See example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent hours looking for solution, I found solution key from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery), and come up with my own:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navSelector = '#toc';
  var $myNav = $(navSelector);

  Toc.init({
    $nav: $myNav,
    $scope: $('.releasenote')
  });

  $('nav#toc ul:first-child').remove();

  var hT = $('#banner').offset().top,
    hH = $('#banner').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#banner').position().top + $('#banner').outerHeight()) {
      console.log('Scrolling down beyoun the banner ');
      $('#toc').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#toc').css('top', 0);
    } else {
      console.log('Scrolling up across banner');
      $('#toc').css('position', 'static');
      $('#toc').css('top', $('#banner').outerHeight(), );
    }
  });

});
```

```css
nav#toc {
  position: static;
}

nav[data-toggle='toc'] {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- add after bootstrap.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.4.1/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.css">
<!-- add after bootstrap.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.4.1/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!-- <link href="dist/bootstrap-toc.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#toc">
  <div class="container">
    <img id="banner" src="https://dummyimage.com/900x400/000/fff" alt="" style="margin: 10px auto;">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- sidebar, which will move to the top on a small screen -->
      <!-- main content area -->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <nav id="toc" class="affix toc-nav" data-spy="affix" data-toggle="toc"></nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9">

        <!-- <div id="menu1" > -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <div class="pbox releasenote">

            <h1 class="text-center" id="release-note">Release Note</h1>
            <h1>0.1.4 (2020-07-06)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed install package from test server via command line.</li>
              <li>Setup tool is able to include icon.</li>
              <li>Read package file from archive format whl and gz file.</li>
              <li>Flexiable Package icon .png or .icon</li>
              <li>Link with tab by link NEWS.rst or CHANGELOG.md.</li>
              <li>Fixed reverse package push record and package record.</li>
              <li>Data clean up on server test, production or both.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.3 (2020-07-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed error package push on reverse record.</li>
              <li>Change browser title, icon, and update footer.</li>
              <li>Fixed error on URL Project when user does not follow our pre-formate in setup.py file.</li>
              <li>Add field PkgVersion to table MKT_PKG_ACCESS_DE to filter package by version</li>
              <li>Able to use ALL keyword in version grant package access to all version.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.2 (2020-06-26)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Update tab title to Morakot Private Package</li>
              <li>Add package platform in user activity</li>
              <li>Download now is classified by version and platform </li>
              <li>User in Morakot Organization and in Test server default can access all pacakge in test server</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.1 (2020-06-21)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Cut branch dev from master</li>
              <li>Add Modules, forms and models</li>
              <li>Adding host, port, http type as configuration</li>
              <li>Adding install and upload instructions</li>
              <li>Update pip install command line.</li>
              <li>Add new widget new release.</li>
              <li>Update user activity to sort by date descending.</li>
              <li>Package user in release history.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.0 (2020-01-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Initial project first version</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.4 (2020-07-06)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed install package from test server via command line.</li>
              <li>Setup tool is able to include icon.</li>
              <li>Read package file from archive format whl and gz file.</li>
              <li>Flexiable Package icon .png or .icon</li>
              <li>Link with tab by link NEWS.rst or CHANGELOG.md.</li>
              <li>Fixed reverse package push record and package record.</li>
              <li>Data clean up on server test, production or both.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.3 (2020-07-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Fixed error package push on reverse record.</li>
              <li>Change browser title, icon, and update footer.</li>
              <li>Fixed error on URL Project when user does not follow our pre-formate in setup.py file.</li>
              <li>Add field PkgVersion to table MKT_PKG_ACCESS_DE to filter package by version</li>
              <li>Able to use ALL keyword in version grant package access to all version.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.2 (2020-06-26)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Update tab title to Morakot Private Package</li>
              <li>Add package platform in user activity</li>
              <li>Download now is classified by version and platform </li>
              <li>User in Morakot Organization and in Test server default can access all pacakge in test server</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.1 (2020-06-21)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Cut branch dev from master</li>
              <li>Add Modules, forms and models</li>
              <li>Adding host, port, http type as configuration</li>
              <li>Adding install and upload instructions</li>
              <li>Update pip install command line.</li>
              <li>Add new widget new release.</li>
              <li>Update user activity to sort by date descending.</li>
              <li>Package user in release history.</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>0.1.0 (2020-01-01)</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>Initial project first version</li>
            </ul>


          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- </div> tab 2 -->

        <!-- /End Tab -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Last but not least, I would like to say Thanks to @[Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6512857/will), the only one to participate in my question. Hope this helps to others. :)