# How to fire javascript function after scroll to specific div bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
        alert('you passed red box bottom')
      })
```

```css
.first-box{height:200px; 
width:300px;
border:1px solid red}

.second-box{
height:200px; 
width:300px;
border:1px solid blue
margin-top:140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box"></div>
<div class="second-box"></div>
```

Hi, I am creating simple app using Vanilla JS, And ran into the problem, I have scroll function, which i want to fire only when, user will pass red box bottom, I have tried to use `element.offsetBottom`, But unfortunately nothing came out, I want to solve this problem only pure javascript, P.S div height is not static It can be increased, depending on the content, any solution?

Comment: Have you seen the [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? Easy way to compare an element’s position relative to the viewport.

Comment: Try this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561480/trigger-event-when-user-scroll-to-specific-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach the bottom of the container you want, you need to use parameter `scrollHeight` of that container. Further, using the condition **if** you compare the current position of `window.scrollY` until this position is equal to `element.scrollHeight`.

```js
var firstbox = document.querySelector(".first-box");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (this.scrollY >= firstbox.scrollHeight) {
    console.log('you passed red box bottom');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.first-box {
  height:200px; 
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.second-box {
  height:200px; 
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid blue
  margin-top:140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box"></div>
<div class="second-box"></div>
```