# Start Jquery animation when reached specific div

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Hi I have this code that gives a type writing effect. But the thigs is that I want the animation to run only when user scroll down to this div. Would you guys be able to help? Thanks

```js
  <script>
 
    $(function(){

        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: ["oru exp", "Oru expertise", '"Our expertise Graphic Designer will create the template based  \n on your company activity and will provide with a proffesional \n and ergonic design to your website."'],
            typeSpeed: 30,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });

        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $("#typed").typed('reset');
        });

    });

    function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

    function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

   
    </script>
```

here is html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="type-wrap">
   <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the html also

Comment: Thanks a lot. So you got any idea how to do that?

Comment: do you have a working example of what you dont want?

Comment: I'm working at university local server, we can't access from outside the network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery trigger action when a user scrolls past a certain part of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627203/jquery-trigger-action-when-a-user-scrolls-past-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(height > 400){
      // $('#your_htmlelement').typed();
  }else{
      // $('#your_htmlelement').typed('reset');
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpXL4/148/)

what about getting the certain height and then play the animation?

Comment: sure thing. was about to post a very similar answer but didn't want to duplicate you.

Comment: Well actually it's a horizontol navigation. So I replaced height by width but now the animation is not working. No errors though..

Comment: @NawshadGhannoo can you show the whole navigation html please?