# How to make left div fixed as it reaches its end until the right bigger div finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have 2 parallel divs, when page is scrolled and a specific div reaches its end I need to stop it from scrolling but continue scrolling for the other div.
[For better example see this website left Div How it Sticks](https://www.snapdeal.com/products/appliances-coffee-makers-kettles?sort=plrty)

Comment: Do you want the other div to stay where it is or keep scrolling up?

Comment: @joey wood my left div have content.so it needs to be scrolled till the end end then make it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627203/jquery-trigger-action-when-a-user-scrolls-past-a-certain-part-of-the-page). Basically whenever the page is scrolling, this will check where you are in the page and you can make a toggle based on that.  I'd recommend once you get to that point on the screen to do an (element you want fixed).addClass()

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.refer the working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.left{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}

.right{
    width: 400px;
    height: 1500px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

}

.right h1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}


</style>


<body>

<div class="left">I am the left div</div>
<div class="right">I am the right div

<h1>bottom</h1>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">


</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but my left div has content so it needs to be scrolled till the end

Comment: change your left div height as your need

Comment: i have given an example of a website take a look at it